# difference between pygame and pygame.SOMETHING

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, import, pygame

Recently, I've been tinkering around with pygame. I noticed that even if I've imported pygame, I can still import pygame.local and pygame.sprite (from... import... to reduce the words I need to type in later). What are the relationships between pygame and pygame.SOMETHING? I thought it was just one pygame module, and now I'm a bit confused. Please give me an explanation or direct me to some articles.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a module `foo` which would have a filename of `foo.py`.

If the contents would look like:

```
# foo.py
def bar():
    return 'bar'


def baz():
    return 'baz'
```

Then you could access the functions `bar` and `baz` in a few ways.
You could import the module as a whole.

```
import foo
print(foo.bar())
```

or individually:

```
from foo import bar
print(bar())
```

You can do both simutaneously as well since the names `foo.bar` and `bar` do not conflict.

Behind the scenes, it's just mapping `foo.bar` and `bar` in the `dict` of `globals` to the same function. You could test this with `print(pygame.sprite is sprite)`.

Obviously there's a lot more going on in a package like `pygame` but the basic premise is `pygame` and `pygame.sprite` are just a name in a `dict`. This is why they can coexist.

A simplistic example of this would be:

```
def bar():
    return 'bar'

foo_dict = {'bar': bar}
globals_dict = {'foo.bar': foo_dict['bar'], 'bar': bar}

# import foo
# foo.bar()
globals_dict['foo.bar']()

# from foo import bar
# bar()
globals_dict['bar']()
```

As you see, it doesn't really matter which you refer to, they both call the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Think of pygame like a library or archive on how to make GUIs in python. You can get a specific book, such as one on how to make sprites, from the library. It is still part of the library, and whether you read it while sitting in the library or after checking it out, it will have the same content.

You can do `from pygame import sprite` to use `sprite()` as a shorthand for `pygame.sprite()` in your code and it will function the same overall.

Comment: Ok, I see. But why does the pygame library contain different modules? I looked up the definition of a library in python, people say that it's just like a module, and a module is a file containing pre-written python code for people to utilize.

Comment: Pygame is the module. I just used library as an analogy. It has functions such as `sprite` that you can umport separately.

Comment: That clears out my doubts, thanks a bunch for replying!